# Can an HTML5 web application (not site) be compatible with IE 6-8

Tags: html, fallback

I noticed some HTML5 apps prompt IE 6-8 users to download Google Chrome Frame to use it. I always wondered why they didn't choose to gracefully degrade. Is it because some HTML5 are simply impossible to reproduce (via external libraries) in older browsers? Or does every new feature have a fallback that these apps simply didn't include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many new features of HTML5 that just won't work on older browsers.  You can attempt to mimic the functionality using JavaScript, and the [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) script library helps HTML5 applications degrade gracefully when they're run on older browsers.  At the end of the day, however, it's like asking for a black and white TV to show 3D high-def movies.

The Google Chrome Frame is a way to basically run Chrome within IE so newer pages will display properly.  This isn't a bad option, but it's not realistic to expect all users to install it.

Answer (score 1):

There are libries that help older browsers implement HTML5 features, [ie9-js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) or [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/), and other libraries, [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/), that will tell you what features the user's browser implements so you can write code to try and degrade gracefully.

However they can't update everything, and they leave you the rest to code around. The developers of the HTML app have lots of work making sure it works on IE9, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc. The easiest way for them to reach all of their users is to tell them to install a plugin or upgrade their browsers.